# Value Type Duration is not allowed on property Duration in XAML

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to do the following with an ordinary Windows Metro style application:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public Duration Duration { get; set; }
}
```

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyButton Duration="0:0:0.2" />
</Grid>
```

But I receive the error: *Value Type Duration is not allowed on property Duration in XAML*

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual Studio 11 Beta XAML compiler.  You cannot set user-defined value type properties via XAML.

This bug has been fixed and the fix should be present in the next release of Visual Studio 11.

Answer (score 0):

For now my workaround has been to expose my duration properties as string...