# Metro XAML - Color Bindings Not Working

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Ive been writing a complex custom control in Metro/XAML using C#.

In order to illustrate my point, I have created a minimal scenario for your considerattion.

A simple custom control is below:

```
public sealed class TestControl : Control
{
    public static DependencyProperty TestTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestText", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string TestText
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TestTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty TestColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestColor", typeof(Color), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Blue));

    public Color TestColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(TestColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TestControl);
    }
}
```

Thie control has two dependency properties, a Text property and a colour property.

Here is my controls standard style in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:TestControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TestControl">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TestText}">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=TestColor}" />
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are two problems:

1) this code wont compile:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
    <local:TestControl x:Name="testcont" TestText="Hello" TestColor="Red"   />
</Grid>
```

The error is:

*Value Type Color is not allowed on property TestColor in XAML BlankPage.xaml*

So it seems that the type converter for Color is broken (I assume).
To get around this, I set the TestColor property in code-behind:

```
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    testcont.TestColor = Colors.Red;
}
```

This allows the code to compile, however the color never gets set correctly in the template. I even used a `ValueConverter`:

```
<TextBlock.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=TestColor, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
</TextBlock.Foreground>
```

But the breakpoint in the `ValueConverter` is never hit, which means that the binding is silently failing somehow.

There seems to be no solution. Can someone shed some light on this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure to use the `System.UI.Color` structure? If so, then you've likely found a bug in the beta (which appears to have been fixed.) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is known issue with value type dependency properties: [Value Type Duration is not allowed on property Duration in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994845/value-type-duration-is-not-allowed-on-property-duration-in-xaml)
MS says that it will be fixed. Currently you can change your property type from Color to Object.

Comment: and note, there is another issue with TemplatedParent bindings: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/741181/relativesource-templatedparent-binding-doesnt-work-in-metro-applications

Comment: Thanks a lot - just had a similar problem and changing the binding from a custom type to object solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Brush`, not a `Color`:

```
testcont.TestColor = Brushes.Red;
```

The DependencyProperty should also be a Brush, not a Color. You could use a Color, but you'd have to convert the color into a Brush.

Comment: I dont want to use a brush, I need to use a Color. In my actual control I am animating Colors with Visual state transitions

Answer (score 0):

There are two namespaces that define color type, `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media`. Your color property is probably of the drawing namespace and the XAML uses the media namespace.

Use a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` type instead of `Color` (again namespace is important), and add `Bindable(true)` attribute for the CLR property.

To demonstrate, look at the Background property declaration on `Control`:

```
[Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
public Brush Background
{
    get
{
    return (Brush)base.GetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty);
}
set
{
    base.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, value);
}
}
```